# Keras / Tensorflow constraint diagonal entry of weight matrix is set to maximum in row

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I would like to set a custom weight constrain in Keras / TensorFlow.

I have a weight matrix W of shape 2dxd for data dimension d (this is the input layer, which takes a datapoint of dimension d and uses its squared values additionally to the normal ones) and I want the diagonal entries of the dxd matrix, which consists of the first d rows of W and the diagonal entries of the dxd matrix, which consists of the last d rows of W to be the maximum weights in the corresponding row.

Is there any easy / cheap way to implement this?

Edit: I splitted w in two diagonal matrices and used

`w-tf.linalg.diag(tf.linalg.diag_part(w))+tf.linalg.diag(tf.keras.backend.max(w,axis=0))`

as constraint but I don't think this is the best (cheapest) implementation